# How can I add my website to IIS again?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis

I removed my website from IIS and now when I try to debug I get the error, `Unable to start debugging on the web server`.  I can take a stab at how to add it again but I don't want to make any mistakes or worse, make a mistake and not even know and it affects things later on down the road and I don't know.  How can I add it again?  Is it possible to do it through visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Properties of the project.  In the Web Tab, hit the button that says "Create Virtual Directory"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the Publish command in the Build menu or right-click on the project in the Project Explorer. In the Service URL set the URL of the web server you want to publish the site on (e.g. localhost), and in the Site/application set the website name(e.g. Default Web Site/your web site).

Comment: I don't know what I need to put into the fields though

Comment: I get a `Web deployment task failed. (Site 'mysite' does not exist')`